# Hypothesis testing for proportions from three populations

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have following problem :

*200 people were surveyed asking about their favorite color. 80 of them said red, 85 blue and 35 said yellow. Verify following hypothesis : proportion of people liking red, blue and yellow color is 5:5:2. Use significance level 0.05.*

I know what to do if I want to test hypothesis about proportion in one population, I also know what to do if I compare proportions in two populations. But what to do if I have three populations? I did some research and I saw that we can use analysis of variance in similar case, but then null hypothesis is that every proportion is equal (and alternative is that at least one isn't). Here I have 5:5:2, so I don't know what to do. I will be grateful for every answer.

Comment: Have you learned about $\chi^2$ tests?

Comment: @MatthewPilling generally yes, but I don't know what do you mean exactly.

Comment: you could try doing a Goodness-of-Fit test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit

Comment: @DavidQuinn, if I understand correctly, you are proposing chi-squared compatibility test, where theoretical values in this case are appropriate fractions ($\frac{5}{12},\frac{5}{12},\frac{2}{12}$)  from these 200 people?

Comment: Yes that's right